# XNA Game Studio and Visual Studio 2012--Wrong Language

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xna-4.0

I just managed to get XNA Game Studio to work with Visual Studio 2012 by following [these](http://ryan-lange.com/xna-game-studio-4-0-visual-studio-2012/)
steps. However, it appears to have only installed in C# language. It is only a template in C#. How can I get it to be a template in Visual Basic? I really need to program in VB, not VCS. Any ideas of how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh477142.aspx)?

Comment: Hmm...thanks for the link, but I'm not sure that helps. You see, it isn't even an option under Visual Basic. There's no "XNA Game Studio" beneath the Workflow folder in Visual Basic section when you try to make a new project. The XNA Game Studio folder is there under C#, but not under Visual Basic. Maybe I just missed something on the page you linked to...                           ---Thanks

Comment: I've never tried to use XNA with VS2012 or VB, only VS2010 C#, but it seems you need XNA Refresh, as said on the page. Do you have that installed? I don't believe VB dev is possible with XNA without it.

Comment: OK, no I don't think I have Refresh. Do you think C# is better for making games anyway?

Comment: That's probably a preference thing. I don't care for VB, but that's just my opinion. There may be performance differences but I can't say. If that's what you know and it's possible then I would say that's best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I get this question so often? How can I install XNA with the latest version of Visual Studio.

The question generally comes from UK Academics still teaching XNA here the latest up to date how to use XNA and Visual Studio 2015.

Thanks to the Open Source Project MXA, XNA now works fine with Visual Studio 2015

XNA is a great framework for creating games, and we use it as a tool to motivate students to learn how to program whilst creating great games at extra-curricular events such as the three thing game.

Many academic still stress

A tool like XNA is an invaluable intrinsic motivator – inspiring students to want to learn to code, as opposed to being motivated because we said so, or because they will get better grades.

1- Download the latest version of this package MXA - XNA 4.0 Refresh for Visual Studio MXA XNA Supports VS2010-2015 see https://mxa.codeplex.com/